# Link files in a folder with Shiny

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

What I want to do is an shiny app that shows the files that are in a folder, and allow to the user to click on it an open/download. Imagine I have 3 files in a folder, like:

```
file1.txt  file2.bmp  file3.jpg
```

What I want is that my app shows me this files and let me click on them to donwload/open. If it where only html, it would be like

```
<a href="file1.txt">file1</a><a href="file2.bmp">file2</a><a href="file3.jpg">file3</a>
```

This must be done dynamically, so when I click on a button, it refresh the list of files that are in the folder and let me download them.

Thanks!

Comment: i added a JS tag because you will more than likely need it for this solution

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple program to browse files, open a file and show its contents.

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
# App title ----
headerPanel("Open a File and Show Contents"),
# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
    label="Data Source",fileInput("fileName", "File Name")),

# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
mainPanel(
    textOutput(outputId = "text"))
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {

inputData <- reactive ({
  if (is.null(input$fileName)) return(NULL)
  inFile <- input$fileName
  conInFile <- file(inFile$datapath,open='read')
  inData <- readLines(conInFile)
  close (conInFile)
  return (inData)
})

output$text <- renderText ({
  inData <- inputData()
  inData
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of files in a folder, you can create a list of those files with

`yourFiles <- list.files(yourDirectory)`.

You can either make a button that refreshes the variable that you assign into, [docs here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/action-buttons.html), or you can poll the folder so that it updates automatically on a timer. You can do that with with `reactivePoll()`, [docs here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactivePoll.html). This will be done in the `server <- function(input, output, session) {yourCodeHere}` section of the app.

The action button docs include an example of how to execute actions, like serving JS download links.